# Map values using two dataframe columns as references

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to map certain values to depending on criteria from two column values.

**Data**

```
id  date    type
aa  Q1.22   hello
aa  Q2.22   hi
aa  Q4.22   hey 
bb  Q3.23   sure
bb  Q4.23   ok
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    type    status
aa  Q1.22   hello   
aa  Q2.22   hi      2000
aa  Q4.22   hey     
bb  Q3.23   sure    
bb  Q4.23   ok      500
```

I would like to place a certain value, ex. 2000 whenever the 'id' is aa and the date is Q1.22
I would like to follow this logic.

**Doing**

```
df['status']=df['id', 'date'].map({'aa': '2000', 'bb': '500'})
```

I am using the map function, however, I only know how to map using one column. I am still researching/experimenting with this. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Are you building out this dictionary (mapping) manually or are values coming from somewhere in a particular form?

Comment: just building it manually- There are about 20 - just wish to map them accordingly based on both column values

Comment: Followup question why is 500 only on line 5 when the last two rows are both `bb Q4.23`?

Comment: let me update that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is by defining the mapping dictionary with keys as tuples holding the required row values of the 2 dataframe columns, as follows:

```
dict1 = {('aa', 'Q2.22'): '2000', ('bb', 'Q4.23'): '500'}
```

Then, to do the mapping:

```
df['status'] = df[['id', 'date']].apply(lambda x: dict1.get((x.id, x.date)), axis=1)
```

or simply:

```
df['status'] = df.apply(lambda x: dict1.get((x['id'], x['date'])), axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   id   date   type status
0  aa  Q1.22  hello   None
1  aa  Q2.22     hi   2000
2  aa  Q4.22    hey   None
3  bb  Q3.23   sure   None
4  bb  Q4.23     ok    500
```

Optionally, if you want to change `None` to blank, you can use:

```
df['status'] = df['status'].fillna('')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   id   date   type status
0  aa  Q1.22  hello       
1  aa  Q2.22     hi   2000
2  aa  Q4.22    hey       
3  bb  Q3.23   sure       
4  bb  Q4.23     ok    500
```

### Edit  (Alternate way to do the mapping):

There is alternate way of coding the mapping more resembling to the desired style of coding, as follows:

```
df['status'] = df[['id', 'date']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(dict1)
```

or put the mapping dictionary `dict1` inline, as follows:

```
df['status'] = df[['id', 'date']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map({('aa', 'Q2.22'): '2000', ('bb', 'Q4.23'): '500'})
```

The last one is the most resembling to the desired style of coding.

Comment: @Lynn  Welcome!  Feel free to let me know if any further clarification required.

Answer (score 1):

Since the mapping structure is being manually assembled, I'd recommend a `DataFrame`.

`mapping_df`:

```
mapping_df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': 'aa', 'date': 'Q2.22', 'status': 2000},
    {'id': 'bb', 'date': 'Q4.23', 'status': 500}
])
```

```
   id   date  status
0  aa  Q2.22    2000
1  bb  Q4.23     500
```

---

Then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df = df.merge(mapping_df, how='left')
```

`df`:

```
   id   date   type  status
0  aa  Q1.22  hello     NaN
1  aa  Q2.22     hi  2000.0
2  aa  Q4.22    hey     NaN
3  bb  Q3.23   sure     NaN
4  bb  Q4.23     ok   500.0
```

---

Optional [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
df = df.merge(mapping_df, how='left')
df['status'] = df['status'].fillna('')
```

```
   id   date   type  status
0  aa  Q1.22  hello        
1  aa  Q2.22     hi  2000.0
2  aa  Q4.22    hey        
3  bb  Q3.23   sure        
4  bb  Q4.23     ok   500.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this